# Query SQL para obtener el SALDO con la diferencia entre deposito y extracción?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mi duda es como generar una consulta que permita conocer el SALDO de cada CUENTA.

La siguiente URL muestro como es el DER:
https://ibb.co/guc470

Comment: Escribe la query que has intentado para echarle un ojo

Comment: podrias agregar el modelo las tablas con los datos minimos necesarios y el query que intentastes, a proposito te invito a hacer el [tour] podras ganarte unas medallas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En extracciones y depósitos tienes el Id de la cuenta por lo que debes es hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT Cta.numero NumeroCuenta, SUM(Dep.monto) - SUM(Ext.monto) Saldo 
FROM Cuentas Cta 
LEFT JOIN depositos Dep ON Cta.id_cuenta = Dep.id_cuenta 
LEFT JOIN extracciones Ext ON Cta.id_cuenta = Ext.id_cuenta
GROUP BY Cta.numero
```

Si es tuya la base de datos recomiendo que los `Id` de la tablas no los llames por ejemplo el de la tabla de Cuentas en vez de `id_cuenta` le coloques solo `"Id"` ya que se entiende que es único para esa tabla. Bueno si tienes alguna otra duda no dejes de consultarme.

Comment: Genial.. hice algo parecido. Pero aun no entiendo porque pones "left join" y no usas "inner join". Porque pienso que se podria usar el inner, viendo que de todas formas lo relacionas por id_cuenta. Eso me marea un poco. Agradeceria una breve esplicacion. Saludoss!!

Comment: Hola! Básicamente he colocado un Left Join para que te traiga Todas las cuentas tengan o no depositos o extracciones, al colocar INNER solo te va a retornar las que tengan datos en todas las tablas. :)  .  podrás usar uno o el otro según el caso y la data que necesites mostrar.  Saludos!!

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!!